# Ruby on Rails login opportunities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I am new to Ruby on Rails.
I want to know which login opportunies are available.
The simple one is:
- eMail and password (plaintext)

I know that is not really the best Idea, but I even know this one.

Can you tell me what I can choose/do else ?
(Encoding/encrypting - Authification etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) is also a good gem to look into. When I first got started with Rails it was easier for me to understand than Devise, and looking back I think it helped me to understand how Rails works overall.

Comment: Yea.. Authlogic looks like the easiest way, BUT I allready have a question: 
There is a UserSession class, but what should I write in ? - Nothing, if I dont want any optional functions like TimeOut ?

Comment: Correct, for the model. You will still need to write a UserSessionController. It looks like you already saw [this](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)... it has details on how to do the controller at the end of the readme.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to go for `Devise` gem, its a **flexible authentication solution** for Rails based on Warden.

Refer to **[Devise Documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)**.

Next option can be to go for `omniauth`. Omniauth will allow you to integrate social websites such as `Facebook`, `Twitter`, `GooglePlus`, etc. authentication. This is one of the popular mechanism these days, as users do not like to create accounts on each website.

Refer to **[Omniauth Documentation](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)**

Offering a user choice between social account or a new account on your website is the best approach. You can combine both `devise + omniauth`.

Comment: Facebook, Twitter and Google+ sounds good, BUT am I able to do this? I am really very new to Ruby on Rails. Devise looks very difficult and Omniauth looks such a lillte bit easier. I think I will try Omniauth.
Thanks for that detailed answer.

Comment: Glad to help. :) Just follow the documentation, you would be able to do it.

Comment: Thats good. And If you face any problem and are not able to resolve it even after googling then you could always post a question for the same with relevant code.Some or the other expert would definitely help you out.

Comment: take a look at [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise), omniauth is actually not that easy to integrate, try with devise, the easies configuration for a single user with devise and a useful workflow it should be: `database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable` this options going in your devise model, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) have more explanation and more options, also you need to be consistent in you database, before run devise migrations uncomment the fields to be consistent with your options

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to use OmniAuth. There are a plenty of documentations in web and its easy to setup. But be careful not to run in the same error I went: Same Origin Policy in JavaScript.

When you call /auth/provider you will receive a link back from the authentication provider that you have to call to get further authentication parameters. Lets say your app runs as http://example.com and Twitter will give you something like this:
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=BtCEsdgasd....

To prevent XSS the browser blocks this Ajax call. Unfortunately I haven't found a valid solution yet ...